# Can't understand the code snippet

Tags: c#

I am doing some basic C# exercises to learn C#.The website provides the solutions to the problems too however, I am unable to understand the code.

**Problem**:
Write a C# program to check if an integer is within 20 of 100 or 200.

**Sample Output:**
Input an integer
25
False

**Solution**:

```
public class Exercise22
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nInput an integer:");
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(result(x));
    }
    public static bool result(int n) 
    { 
        //Can't understand the code below - 
        //why is the "<=10" and "return false" used 

        if (Math.Abs(n - 100) <= 10 || Math.Abs(n - 200) <= 10)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: if the condition passes, your method returns true, otherwise false. Usually you´d need an else-statement. However as you´re *returning* from the previous branch (the `if`-statement) you can omit it, because there´s no way to the `return false`-statement other than the condition *not* passing.

Comment: "I don't understand" isn't an answerable question.  *What* don't you understand?  When you step through this code in a debugger, what behavior do you observe?  What different behavior did you expect?  Why?

Comment: @David He wrote what he doesn't understand in the code as comments.

Comment: @Zane You got several answers to your question - look below.

Comment: @Zane "within 20 of 100 or 200" means from 90 to 110 or from 190 to 210.

Comment: Ah... well if you did not understand the task, then of course you don't understand the solution. It means that the value should be between 90 and 110 _or_ between 190 and 210.

Comment: Wouldn't "within 20 of 100" be *80-120*?

Comment: @David I agree with you, but the solution of the problem is using <= 10.

Comment: @ElmoDev001: Then the solution doesn't match the problem statement.  One of the two is incorrect (or at least unclear to the point of being invalid).  I would recommend that the OP find a different tutorial.

Comment: @RenéVogt, could you please explain how did you come up with "between  90 and 110 or between 190 and 210"

Comment: @Zane  I have to admit that I have my problems with the grammar in the problem description. But that's what the code actually does. So if David is right, then the proposed solution is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Math.Abs()` gives you the absolute value of the argument.

If `n` is between 90 and 110 (within 20 around 100), then `n-100` is between `-10` and `10`, so `Math.Abs()` will return a value between `0` and `10`.

The same is done for 200.

You could however simplify this to:

```
return Math.Abs(n-100) <= 10 || Math.Abs(n-200) <= 10;
```

So if `n` is in one of the ranges, `true` is returned and the function ends.

Otherwise, the function skips the `return true` and continues to `return false`.

Comment: I still don't understand how you guys are converting "within 20 of 100" to "80 and 110", please explain

Comment: @Zane I explained what the code does, it checks for "90-110". I can't explain the english grammar of the problem description, I'm no native speaker. Your question was to understand the code, that's what I explained.

Answer (score 1):

`if` is obviously a condition, following statements are only executed when the condition passes. In your case execution will leave the method by executing `return true`.

I assume you think you´d need an `else` to indicate what happens when the condition does *not* pass. Usually this is right. However in this special case there´s no way to reach the `return false`-statement when the `if` passes, as in this case (as described earlier) the method will terminate.

So you could also write this, which is completely identical:

```
if (Math.Abs(n - 100) <= 10 || Math.Abs(n - 200) <= 10)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

So all in all there´s no other way that the `return false`-statement is executed than the condition evaluating to `false`.